# Blackberry WebWorks HTML5 Eksternal Image Won't show up

Tags: image, blackberry-webworks

I'm a newbie in developing on smartphone. After a short research, I choose BlackBerry WebWorks  SDK.

My Device is 8530 (CDMA), Internet Connection through WiFi.

On my index.html, I need to show image with src from external link, for example
 `<img src="http://www.domainname.com/img/example.jpg">`

No Luck, it won't show up. If the source is local image, it's work fine.

I already change the `<access uri="*" subdomains="true"/>` on config.xml also the image still don't show up.

Looking the answer on blackberry and  stackoverflow forum with no luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the uri="*" access element would show the image.  Another recommendation is to explicitly white list the domain that your image is coming from, like this:

Can you confirm that your page is loading fine, but its just the image that isn't appearing?